# error: column "undefined" does not exist postgres to_tsquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Hi im getting a unidentifiable error from postgres. Would anyone be able to lead me towards to right solution?

```
'SELECT * FROM photo'+ 
        ' JOIN collection ON (photo.collection_id = collection.id)'+
        ' JOIN photographer ON (photo.photographer_id = photographer.id)'+
        ` WHERE collection.title = ${category} AND to_tsvector(photo.decription||' '||photographer.name ||' '||photographer.location||' '||photographer.bio||' '||photographer.name||' '|| photographer.twitter_username||' '||photographer.instagram_username) @@ to_tsquery(${text})`,
```

the error reads

```
error: column "undefined" does not exist
```

Comment: Please show the actual generated SQL statement.

Comment: As stated by others, the issue is with your javascript, not postgres. One or more of the values you're using to build the SQL statement is undefined. Print your statement before executing it to find out which.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the select you try to run is from node.js.
In that case,

1. check if variables 'category' and 'text' are initialized with real value,
   it seems to me that one of them is 'undefined'
2. watch out for condition `collection.title = ${category}` - category is probable string, in that case, quotes are missing, so it should be:
   `collection.title = '${category}'`
   the same problem may appear with 'text' too, `to_tsquery(${text})`
   changes to `to_tsquery('${text}')`

Answer (score 1):

I believe in your JS code you have a problematic variable value. So the variable returns `undefined` which is directly and unescaped put into the query. The query interprets the text `undefined` as column name which is, naturally, not existing.

My guess: Check the `category` and `text` variables in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

whoever from the future if you have to deal with this

```
'SELECT * FROM photo'+ 
        ' JOIN collection ON (photo.collection_id = collection.id)'+
        ' JOIN photographer ON (photo.photographer_id = photographer.id)'+   
        ` WHERE collection.title = ${category}`+
        ` AND to_tsvector(CONCAT(photo.description, '' ,photographer.name, '' ,photographer.location, '' ,photographer.bio, '' ,photographer.name, '' ,photographer.twitter_username, '' ,photographer.instagram_username)) @@ to_tsquery(${req.body.searchBody})`
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: If that is direct text interpolation then you are leaving yourself wide open to an SQL injection hack too. Don't do that.